# Ajax wont call when output from another ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have comment system using live ajax php, and also include for vote system on that comment

Logic: when i post new comment, system will call ajax function with method post, and display response in above of textarea for comment, that response is include vote system (a class="with_unique_id"), but when i click that vote, it wont calling ajax function (nothing happend in browser console), whereas in current comment that displaying in above of new comment, it working fine.

This is my ajax code for vote

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $(".voteMe").click(function() {
        var voteId = this.id;
        var upOrDown = voteId.split('_'); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('blog/likepost');?>/"+upOrDown[0],
            cache: false,               
            data:'voteId='+upOrDown[0] + '&upOrDown=' +upOrDown[1],
            success: function(response){                
                try{
                    if(response=='true'){   
                        var newValue = parseInt($("#"+voteId+'_result').text()) + 1;            
                        $("#"+voteId+'_result').html(newValue);
                        document.getElementById('likeStatus_'+upOrDown[0]).innerHTML = 'Success';
                        $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0]).show();
                        setTimeout(function() { $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0]).hide(); }, 5000);             
                    }else{
                        $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0]).show();
                        document.getElementById('likeStatus_'+upOrDown[0]).innerHTML = 'Liked';
                        setTimeout(function() { $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0]).hide(); }, 5000);
                    }
                }catch(err) {       
                    alert(err.message);
                }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to read your code, but I guess this is the root cause:

```
 if(response=='true'){   
                    var newValue = parseInt($("#"+voteId+'_result').text()) + 1;            
                    $("#"+voteId+'_result').html(newValue);
                    document.getElementById('likeStatus_'+upOrDown[0]).innerHTML = 'Success';
                    $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0]).show();
                    setTimeout(function() { $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0]).hide(); }, 5000);             
                }
```

This line here:

```
$("#"+voteId+'_result').html(newValue);
```

That become the link you want to click again. Right? 
If that is so, then you need to re-assign the event handler.
By replacing the DOM element, you have also removed the assigned event handler

PS: You code is very hard to read. It will be nightmare for you to maintain it.

Comment: I try to understand that you mean, but sorry, im not understand.
but i have fixed my code with adding same ajax code function in response of current ajax with different id.
thankyou

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain. There are several occurences of `$("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0])`. That is inefficient because jQuery has to find the element every time. You should store it in a variable.   This is also wrong `var newValue = parseInt($("#"+voteId+'_result').text()) + 1;` - server should return the current value. Client should never calculated because it is not reliable.  Third point: WTF is this?? `document.getElementById('likeStatus_'+upOrDown[0]) vs $("#likeStatus_"+upOrDown[0])` - it does almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed my code with adding same ajax code function in response of current ajax with different id.
thankyou